# I want the user to see posts which are within 1 km radius of him/her. How to do that? Please see details

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, firebase, android-geofence, geofire

I am storing some posts on `Firebase` along with the `currentLatitude` and `currentLongitude` of the location from where it was posted.

Now, what I want is I want the user to see only those posts which are in 1 km radius of him/her.

I know about `GeoFire`, but the problem is that I have updated my whole project to the latest `Firebase` SDK and the present `GeoFire` library is not compatible with the latest `Firebase` SDK.

I also tried using [Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html), but I am not getting how to do this with it.

I would be highly thankful if you recommend me some alternatives or the way of achieving what I want. Please!

Comment: You would either build a library that can query on the two values using a single property. You'll end up with something very similar to Geofire. Or you could use Geofire. If it's not updated yet, you can fork it and update.

Comment: Note that there's an open pull request that makes Geofire compatible with the latest Firebase SDK. https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/pull/24 It's not been released yet for various reasons, but you could use that as the basis for your own work.

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen hey, thanks again. One thing I want to know is that after forking and updating it how would I be using it my app? Would I be downloading the whole example or how?

Comment: After forking and updating as given here: github.com/firebase/geofire-java/pull/24 when I added `compile 'com.firebase:geofire:2.0.0` to my project, it gave me this error: `Error:(47, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebase:geofire:2.0.0` How can I use this library now? Please reply, sir.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please reply sir. I really want help with this. Please!

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. First, working with two values (Latitude & Longitude) brings in limitation on mathematical end to get the radius-circle area. One way to overcome this is by using GeoHash https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash
and based on the accuracy the zoom level can be set.
Few references which can be helpful are https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18330/would-it-be-possible-to-use-geohash-for-proximity-searches

Within firebase:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/09/geofire-location-queries-for-fun-and.html

Google Maps API also has rich geometry features which can be explored
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical

Other alternative can be using a geo-spatial tool like PostGreSql/PostGis database, which has powerful functions to check within a set radius https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77072/return-all-results-within-a-30km-radius-of-a-specific-lat-long-point